# How to Upload Text File content to a listBox Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, listbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to upload some comma separated numbers from a text file to a listbox using Jquery and i dont want the page to reloading when the upload button has been click.

I want to populate all the content inside the listbox.

Example of text file content:

```
123422234
243653718
353721838
354729839
263748239
```

OR

```
123422234, 243653718, 353721838, 354729839, 263748239
```

Will really Appreciate any help thanks...

this is my list box in MVC5

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipient, Model.Recipients, new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "recipientList" })
```

And the Upload file Path

```
<label><strong>Recipients From File</strong> </label>
                        <div class="well" style="margin-bottom:-15px;">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { Class = "span12", type = "file", id = "file" })
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="Upload" value="Upload" />
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="clearFile" value="Clear" />
```

That's all I have, How do I go about with the upload??

Comment: You could show us your markup and any code that you've already tried and how far the code took you.

Comment: Just added some markup did...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.get('file_to_read.txt', function(data) {
       do_something_with(data)
    });

function  do_something_with(data){
   var str ="<ul>";
    var arr = data.split('/');
    var lastID =arr.length-1;
    $each(arr ,function( index,lidata ) {
       str+="<li>"+lidata+"</li>"
       if (i == lastID) {
         str ="<ul>";
        $('#parentelement').html(str);
       }
    });

}
```